# Why is the second difference matrix of size n-2 x n in l1 trend filtering?

Tags: matlab, filtering

The l1 trend filtering is expressed by taking $||Dx||_1$  where D is the second difference matrix why is taken of size (n-2)xn rather than circulant matrix of size nxn. I have implemented in both ways but there is not much difference in the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a periodic signal then you naturally take a circulant matrix. However, in the non-periodic case the values at begin and end of the signal are unrelated, so it makes no sense to consider the wrap-around differences. Thus the convolution with with the filter of length 3 gives $n-(3-1)=n-2$ complete linear combinations in the "inner" segment of the product.